# last status of a policy at a point in time

Tags: mdx

i am trying to get the last status of a policy at a particular point in time. For example, we have the following information stored in sql server table:

```
TrackerId,policyNumber,statusDescription,YearMonthDay,YearMonth
1   a   active  2000-01-01  2000-01
2   b   active  2000-01-02  2000-01
3   c   active  2000-01-03  2000-01
4   d   active  2000-01-04  2000-01
5   e   active  2000-01-05  2000-01
6   b   suspended   2000-02-01  2000-02
7   c   cancelled   2000-02-02  2000-02
8   b   reinstated  2000-03-01  2000-03
9   e   cancelled   2000-03-02  2000-03
10  f   active  2000-04-01  2000-04
11  g   active  2000-04-02  2000-04
```

From the above, i am trying to the get the result in the following format in mdx

```
date,openingBalance,new business,reinstated,lapse,cancelled/suspended,closing balance
2000-01 0   5   0   0   0   5
2000-02 5   0   0   0   2   3
2000-03 3   0   1   0   0   4
2000-04 4   2   0   0   1   5
```

"New business" are those policies that were new in the month i.e "Active".  The same applies for statuses "Lapsed", "Cancelled" and "Suspended".

I have the following dimensions:  `Status`, `Time`, `Policy`.

Calculating "New Business", "Reinstated", "Lapse" and "Cancelled/suspended" is straight forward like so:

```
member [Measures].[New Business] as
([Status].[Status].&[1],[Measures].[Policy Count])

member [Measures].[Suspended] as
([Status].[Status].&[2],[Measures].[Policy Count])

member [Measures].[Cancelled] as
([Status].[Status].&[3],[Measures].[Policy Count])

member [Measures].[Suspended+Cancelled] as
([Measures].[Suspended]+[Measures].[Cancelled])

member [Measures].[Reisntated] as
([Status].[Status].&[4],[Measures].[Policy Count])

member [Measures].[Lapsed] as
([Status].[Status].&[5],[Measures].[Policy Count])
```

My problem is formulating the calculated member for "Closing Balance" and "Opening Balance".  The logic behind "closing balance" is that it should give me all active policies as at that time.  e.g as at "2000-02" policyNumber [a],[d],[e] are active and [b] and [c] are suspended and cancelled respectively.  So my closing balance should read "3".

Any help would be appreciated.